# How to put the correct data type into function for Byte_t *Data?

Tags: c

I am developing for BLE Send/Receive data. I have some issue for data type change.

The type of the BLE Send Data function is like the following:

```
typedef unsigned char Byte_t;                   /* Generic 8 bit Container.   */
static void SPPLEDataIndicationEvent(DeviceInfo_t *DeviceInfo, unsigned int DataLength, Byte_t *Data)
```

I add a char array and set the data like the following:

```
#define ReservedCode                                   0x01
#define Sensor_TypeCode                                0xEA
static Byte_t         *SensorData;
SensorData[0]=ReservedCode;             
SensorData[1]=ReservedCode;           
SensorData[2]=Sensor_TypeCode;      
SensorData[3]=Sensor_TypeCode;              
SensorData[4]=Sensor_TypeCode;
```

And I have try the following , but it seems did not working. The BLE App did not receive any data. (I am sure the `DeviceInfo` is no problem here.)

```
SPPLEDataIndicationEvent(DeviceInfo, sizeof(SensorData), SensorData);
```

How to put the correct data into **SPPLEDataIndicationEvent** function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pointer is pointing to undefined address. It is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

You must init your pointer

```
Byte_t  *SensorData = malloc(requested_size);
if (SensorData != NULL)
{
    // your stuff
}
free(SensorData);
```

Or declare it as an array

```
static Byte_t SensorData[requested_size];
```

Answer (score 0):

`SensorData` is just a pointer, it hold's no value. You need to actually allocate memory for it.

Changing the definition of `SensorData` to:

```
static Byte_t SensorData[5];
```

will fix your problem.

A wonder your program did run at all, you are accessing data you're not supposed to access.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add following line to allocate memory for your `SensorData` array:

```
SensorData=malloc(sizeof(Byte_t)*5);
```

Or you would get "segmentation fault" while you try to access `SensorData[]`.